# How to get dataset member value by getProperty() in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to get value of dataset member value by Puppeteer of:

```
<div class="myClass" data-val1="A" data-val2="B" data-val3="C" someid="1"></div>
```

Then in Puppeteer script to get value of *className* property I do:

```
let mylselector = await page.waitForSelector('div[class="myClass"]');
let myid = await (await myselector.getProperty('className')).jsonValue();
```

But how can I get value of *data-val2*? In Properties of the div element in Developer Tools of the browser I can see that all *data-* elements are members of 'dataset: DOMStringMap'. What I can see there as well it appears under 'attributes: NamedNodeMap'.

When trying to reach 'dataset' or 'attributes' by:

```
let myid = await myselector.getProperty('dataset');
```

I get error:

```
Protocol error (DOM.describeNode): Object id doesn't reference a Node
```

Update/more details:

when I do:

```
console.log(await appframe.waitForSelector('div[class="myClass"]'));
```

then it prints:

```
CdpElementHandle {
  handle: CdpJSHandle {},
  [Symbol(_isElementHandle)]: true
}
```

next, when try:

```
console.log(await(await appframe.waitForSelector('div[class="myClass"]')).handle);
```

then I get only CdpJSHandle:

```
CdpJSHandle {}
```

now I still can get single, named property by:

```
console.log(await(await(await(await appframe.waitForSelector('div[class="myClass"]')).handle).getProperty('className')).jsonValue());
```

but when try to getProperties() on it ends with same error:

```
console.log(await(await(await appframe.waitForSelector('div[class="myClass"]')).handle).getProperties());
```

Comment: Be aware that `mylselector` will probably be a list of elements.

Answer (score 0):

I basically never use `getProperty` or `jsonValue` and, in general, try to avoid working with element handles when possible. Using these makes the script verbose, confusing to write and requires multiple CDP trips. They're mostly unnecessary.

I would suggest using an `evaluate`-family function, which lets you use the native DOM you're already familiar with, work synchronously, write less code, and use only a single CDP trip (two, if you need to use `waitForSelector()`):

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.6.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<div class="myClass" data-val1="A" data-val2="B" data-val3="C" someid="1"></div>
</body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const p = console.log;
  const sel = ".myClass";
  const el = await page.waitForSelector(sel);
  p(await el.evaluate(el => el.dataset.val1)); // => A
  p(await el.evaluate(el => el.dataset.val2)); // => B
  p(await el.evaluate(el => el.dataset.val3)); // => C
  p(await el.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute("someid"))); // => 1

  // or use $eval:
  const everything = await page.$eval(sel, el => ({
    val1: el.dataset.val1,
    val2: el.dataset.val2,
    val3: el.dataset.val3,
    someid: el.getAttribute("someid"),
  }));
  p(everything);
    // => { val1: 'A', val2: 'B', val3: 'C', someid: '1' }

  // if there are multiple elements:
  const everythingAll = await page.$$eval(
    sel,
    els => els.map(el => el.dataset.val1)
  );
  p(everythingAll); // =>  [ 'A' ]
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

While you're at it, avoid attribute selectors like `'div[class="myClass"]'`. `'div.myClass'` is less verbose and more reliable--if the `<div>` class becomes `'myClass red-border'`, then the super-specific attribute selector will fail unnecessarily. Generally, only use attribute syntax when you must disambiguate between multiple classes, or you want to use a `$=`, `^=`, `*=`-family operation to select on substrings of an attribute.

Bonus points for dropping `div` in the selector and simply using `.myClass`. Specifying the `div` is probably unnecessary, unless the class exists on non-`div` elements and you need to ignore them.

Also avoid `await (await (await foo()).bar())`-style coding. This is difficult to read and too clever--break the code onto multiple lines with intermediate variables.